# Decrement a float from 1 down to 0, in 0.01 increments

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-point-precision

As the title states, I'd like to start from 1 and decrement with by 0.01 all the way down to zero.

Problem is, I'm using floats and I keep getting values such as `0.5000000001`.

Comment: Please provide more context on what you are trying to achieve; perhaps `float` is not suitable for your task.

Comment: 0.01 cannot be represented in binary float, so you should use int instead

Comment: This is similar to having an `int` starting at `25` and wanting to decrement by `2.5` all the way to `0`. It isn't possible, because your decrement value isn't representable, and when you approximate it (with something that is representable), it doesn't divide your value perfectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use an int, Start at 100 decrement down to 0 and divide the value by 100.0

```
for (int i=100; i>=0; --i)
{    
    float f = i/100.0f;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not that performance would be limited by these operations, but it is likely to be faster to use a float index `i` going down from `100.0f` to `0.0f`. Besides, note that `float f = i/100.0;` risks making the compiler generate a double-precision division followed by a conversion to single-precision. The declaration `float f = i/100.0f;` is equivalent (for complicated reasons that the compiler may not know how to take advantage of) and more straightforward to compile.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm.